# Apartment current_tenant resets to 'public' after failed devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rack, apartment-gem, rack-middleware

I use Devise for authentication and Apartment for multi-tenancy support on a SAAS app.

After a failed login, devise "redirects" to the login page (Users::SessionsController#new) and the value of `Apartment::Tenant.current` which was previously set in a `TenantElevator` middleware goes back to its default value of "public".

This is happening because Devise isn't actally redirecting to the login page but calling the FailureApp (which renders the login page) with a new rack env and returning its response. The new rack app doesn't have `TenantElevator` middleware so the tenant isn't set within the rack app.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Maybe a way I can add the TenantElevator middleware to the Failure app?

Comment: Could this just be Devise clearing out the session on a failed login?

Comment: @TarynEast I doubt that. Apartment gem doesn't store the Tenant in Session.

Comment: Re-asking the exact same question to push it to the top is not a good behavior.

Comment: https://github.com/influitive/apartment#middleware-considerations

Comment: @max It's a different question, I edited this some minutes ago as I became sure it was a middleware issue. This discusses a problem anyone that uses Devise and Apartment gem will run into.

The other ask how to add a middleware to devise Failure app which I believe might be useful for fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on this and figured providing an answer may be useful for someone.

Haven't encountered this issue in a while, but looking through the sourcecode of the app I was working on, I fixed this issue by simply modifying where the apartment's middleware is inserted i.e modifying the order of the middleware.

Add the following snippet at the very bottom of your apartment.rb initializer file which should be located at app/config/initializers/apartment.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, Apartment::Elevators::Domain
```

Essentially, insert your middleware before the ShowExceptions middleware, this ensures Devise, and ShowExceptions middleware, always runs under/within the context of the tenant set by whatever TenantElevator your app uses.

There may currently be a better way to handle this -- I am not sure, but this was the best option I found back when I had this issue.