# Add middleware to Devise failure app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, middleware, rack-middleware

After a failed login Devise seems to be calling the failure app in a new rack env and returning it's response which is typically the login page.

How do I add a middleware to devise failure app?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish? You can customize the failure app by `config.warden { |manager| manager.failure_app = CustomFailure }` - if you for example want your rails application routes to handle the error you can use `MyAppName::Application.routes`.

Comment: @max see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075966/apartment-current-tenant-resets-to-public-after-failed-devise-login